# How to get dynamic list when key is unknown in html form

Tags: html, angular, ionic3

I am working on angular application. i am able to display list witch has key value
see example

```
  <ion-item *ngFor="let list of lists" [(ngModel)]="lists" 
        <ion-row>

            <ion-col col-7 class="title">
                {{ list.accountName}}
```

> how to display list when key and array both are dynamic 
>   for example i want to display
>     list=[{key1:"fd",key2:"fdf"}]

in html page i dont khow what is key 1 or key 2 it will come dynamic or every time key will change so how to print 
{{array.unkhownkey}

i have another solution
how to merge if i will get key in 2 different list and list in different list
for example
{{array}}.{{key}}

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your issue and/or make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a pipe which you can inject in *ngFor html.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'forArrayProp'
})
export class ForArrayProp implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: {}): string[] {

    if (!value) {
      return [];
    }

    return Object.keys(value);
  }
}
```

Then in templates:

```
<div *ngFor="let property of response">
    <div *ngFor="let itemkey of property | forArrayProp">
         {{property[itemkey]}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Pipe

```
<div *ngFor="let list of lists" [(ngModel)]="lists" >
    <ion-item *ngFor="let key of list | keys" >
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col col-7 class="title">
                {{key}}: {{c[key]}}
            </ion-col>
       </ion-row>
    </ion-item>
</div>
```

ts

```
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'keys'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
    let keys = [];
    for (let key in value) {
      keys.push(key);
    }
    return keys;
  }
}
```